# python file read error jsonfile, can somebody help me with this problem

Tags: python, json, directory

I am trying to read JSON file which is the next parent folder

Here is my code (it's just a simple code but I cannot solve the problem):

```
file = '/studentjson/senin/userfollowing.json'
json_data = open(file).read()
json_obj = json.loads(json_data)
```

here is the error :

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PythonProjects/ScrapyTutorial/venv/database.py", line 8, in <module>
    json_data = open(file).read()
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/studentjson/senin/userfollowing.json'
```

Comment: Did you try to use the full path of file?

Comment: '/studentjson/senin/userfollowing.json' looks like an absolute path, from root. But looks like on your machine the path would be "D:...". If you want the path from the current working directory, maybe remove the first slash?

Comment: @Gabip yes I did, and i get more error as:   File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 11826: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @GabrielTrégoat I get more error when I removed the first slash

Comment: There are 2 different errors - when you use the path from the snippet above the you get `FileNotFound` which means that the path is incorrect. When you use the full path, you get another error of encoding, which means that the file was found.
Try: `open('full/path/to/file', encoding='utf-8')`

Comment: I think Gabip's way should work. 
For what I wrote, if you remove the first slash, that means your path will be relative to the current work directory, so it will not find the path either if current_work_dir/studentjson/senin/userfollowing.json isn't the full path. Relative paths are useful because they allow you to write code that can execute on any machine without having to change the absolute path every time.